# How to point to new install Opencv with PythonPath?

Tags: opencv, installation, version, pythonpath

After installing and building opencv 4.0 [with this script](https://github.com/AastaNV/JEP/blob/master/script/install_opencv4.0.0_Nano.sh), I import opencv with python and checked the version. It prints 3.2.0 instead of 4.0.0

I also found a few others with the [same problem here](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1049296/jetson-nano/how-to-install-opencv-python-for-python3-6/2). The answer is to **export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:${OpenCV DIR}/release/python**

I'm not to familiar with using Python paths but I assume the correct statement to use is **export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:${opencv-4.0.0}/release/python_loader** and reload bashrc.  Is this the right way to load the recently installed opencv for python?

Here is what my directory looks like
https://i.stack.imgur.com/3hc2s.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

export PYTHONPATH=~/opencv/opencv-4.0.0/release/lib/python3

Comment: Can you add some description to this code to help us understand how this answers the question?

Comment: Wouldn't this need also the previous path? `export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:~/opencv/opencv-4.0.0/release/lib/python3`